# Seemingly random system crashes on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

EDIT: Oops, don't know why I originally said 12.10. This is 12.04.

This is a work laptop and I didn't really use it over the Christmas break (22nd to Jan 1st). However, I have had three complete system crashes (Jan 3rd, 4th and 7th) since coming back. The complete system crash is everything will become unresponsive. No mouse/keyboard input. I have a system monitor indicator that will stop updating on screen. Can't move to a terminal session with Ctrl+Alt+F1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6. Not responding to pings or ssh connections. Lastly, it is a System76 Serval Professional 7. Two light indicators on the laptop will just be flashing (caps lock and I believe screen lock lights).

In addition, I can't find anything in logs related to it and the syslog has actually not updated anything since December 18th 9:17. That seems problematic that syslog has no updates have occurred since then.

Lastly, I did have some Ubuntu package updates right around that time:

```
$ zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
...
Start-Date: 2012-12-18  09:21:00
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.82'
Install: linux-headers-3.2.0-35:amd64 (3.2.0-35.55), linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-35.55), linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-35.55)
Upgrade: linux-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.34.37, 3.2.0.35.40), supermeatboy:amd64 (1.1-0ubuntu3, 1.1-0ubuntu4), apport:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu15, 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1), python-problem-report:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu15, 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.34.37, 3.2.0.35.40), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.34.37, 3.2.0.35.40), python-apport:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu15, 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.2.0-34.53, 3.2.0-35.55), unity-lens-applications:amd64 (5.12.0-0ubuntu1, 5.18.0-0ubuntu1), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu15, 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1)
End-Date: 2012-12-18  09:23:54
...
```

Let me know if I can supply anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

generally hard freezes like this are hardware related or in this case something related to your kernel upgrade. see the linux-image-generic (3.2.0.34.37, 3.2.0.35.40) line of your log.

also the lack of logs is very odd indeed. what does df -h say for your / partition. also if you do not have logs check

dmesg | less

Comment: `$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       452G   99G  330G  24% /`

Comment: how about dmesg anything there related to syslog.

Comment: Did a search for syslog in dmesg and nothing. I installed experimental nvidia drivers back in November for the Steam Client. I have set it back to a non-experimental driver and haven't had a crash yet. Not really proof that fixed it, though.

Comment: could be driver related, still concerned about lack of logs, is that resolved?